# Adjuntar archivo a correo descargado con mailkit protocolo imap C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

Estimados estoy usando la libreria de mailkitimap esto lo que permite es usar el protocolo para descargar el servidor de correo

mi situacion es la siguiente, tengo una clase que descarga los correos y me los envia a mi función, dentro de estos parametro me envia el uid por lo que con ese parametro puedo descargar el correo del servidor pero quiero una vez descargado el correo adjuntarle un archivo .txt

mi código es el siguiente:

```
 public static void GestionarCorreos(Correo CorreoRecibido)
        {
            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect(CorreoRecibido.cliente, CorreoRecibido.puerto, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                    client.Authenticate(CorreoRecibido.usuario, CorreoRecibido.contraseña);
                    client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

                    var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(CorreoRecibido.uid);
//aca ya recibo el correo message <- a esa variable quiero adjuntar un txt



                    var TodasLasCarpetas = client.Inbox.GetSubfolders(); // todas las sub carpetas de inbox
                    if (!ExisteCarpeta(TodasLasCarpetas,CorreoRecibido.carpetareceptora))
                    {
                        client.Inbox.Create(CorreoRecibido.carpetareceptora, true); // Crea una carpeta en el servidor
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        client.Inbox.MoveTo(CorreoRecibido.uid, client.Inbox.GetSubfolder(CorreoRecibido.carpetareceptora)); // mueve un correo de carpeta
                    }
                    client.Disconnect(true);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error -> " + ex.Message);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }


            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la seccion del codigo que realiza lo necesitado, basicamente adjuntar un txt al correo y luego lo añade al servidor posterior a eso el correo original lo marca como eliminado dejando la copia con el adjunto

```
var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(CorreoRecibido.uid);

                    var attachment = new MimePart("text/plain", "txt")
                    {
                        ContentObject = new ContentObject(File.OpenRead(CorreoRecibido.AdjuntoProcesado.Name)),
                        ContentBase = uri,
                        ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId(),
                        ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.Attachment),
                        ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(CorreoRecibido.AdjuntoProcesado.Name)
                    };

                    // creando el contenedor del mensaje de texto y el archivo adjunto
                    var multipart = new Multipart("mixed");
                    multipart.Add(message.Body);
                    multipart.Add(attachment);

                    message.Body = multipart;
                    var idconattach =  client.Inbox.Append(message);
                    client.Inbox.AddFlags(CorreoRecibido.uid, MessageFlags.Deleted, true);
                    var TodasLasCarpetas = client.Inbox.GetSubfolders(); // todas las sub carpetas de inbox
                    if (!ExisteCarpeta(TodasLasCarpetas, CorreoRecibido.carpetareceptora))
                    {
                        client.Inbox.Create(CorreoRecibido.carpetareceptora, true); // Crea una carpeta en el servidor
                        client.Inbox.MoveTo(idconattach.Value, client.Inbox.GetSubfolder(CorreoRecibido.carpetareceptora)); // mueve un correo de carpeta
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        client.Inbox.MoveTo(idconattach.Value, client.Inbox.GetSubfolder(CorreoRecibido.carpetareceptora)); // mueve un correo de carpeta
                    }
                    client.Inbox.AddFlags(idconattach.Value, MessageFlags.Seen, true); // si se quiere volver a marcar como no leido se debe cambiar a removeflags()

                    client.Disconnect(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este código:

```
        public static void GestionarCorreos(Correo CorreoRecibido)
        {
            using(var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect(CorreoRecibido.cliente, CorreoRecibido.puerto, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                    client.Authenticate(CorreoRecibido.usuario, CorreoRecibido.contraseña);
                    client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

                    MimeKit.MimeMessage message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(CorreoRecibido.uid);
                    //aca ya recibo el correo message <- a esa variable quiero adjuntar un txt

                    var attachment = new MimePart("text/plain", "txt")
                    {
                        Content = new MimeContent(File.OpenRead("archivo.txt")),
                        ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.Attachment),
                        ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName("archivo.txt")
                    };

                    // creando el contenedor del mensaje de texto y el archivo adjunto
                    var multipart = new Multipart("mixed");
                    multipart.Add(message.Body);
                    multipart.Add(attachment);

                    message.Body = multipart;

                    var TodasLasCarpetas = client.Inbox.GetSubfolders(); // todas las sub carpetas de inbox
                    if (!ExisteCarpeta(TodasLasCarpetas, CorreoRecibido.carpetareceptora))
                    {
                        client.Inbox.Create(CorreoRecibido.carpetareceptora, true); // Crea una carpeta en el servidor
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        client.Inbox.MoveTo(CorreoRecibido.uid, client.Inbox.GetSubfolder(CorreoRecibido.carpetareceptora)); // mueve un correo de carpeta
                    }
                    client.Disconnect(true);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error -> " + ex.Message);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: amigo estaba bien pero me da un error en el mime part en la parte content y new mimecontent() me da error no lo reconoce como parte del MimePart